# How to use regex to parse this json: { "success" : true }?

Tags: json, regex, bash

I am using a shell script to make an API call and I need to verify that the json response is this:

```
{ "success" : true }
```

I am able to echo the call response to see that it has that value but I need to validate the response in an if statement so that the script can continue, I have tried to do this a number of ways with no success

1. Regex - I have used regex to extract values from other json responses, but I have not found a regex pattern that can extract the value of "success" with this json
2. String Comparison - I thought of simply using this condition to attempt to match the strings:

   if [ "$callResponse" = '{ "success" : true }' ]

However I quickly ran into issues with the script reading the json due to its special characters, I tried using sed to add a backslash before each special character but sed could not read the json either

3. Lastly I tried to pipe the response to python but got the error "ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded" when using this command:

   status=${$callResponse | python -c "import sys, json; print(json.load(sys.stdin)['success'])"}

---

Does anyone know a regex pattern that could find that specific json string? Is there another simple solution to this issue?

(Note that it is not possible to download jq or any other utilities for this PC)

Comment: I would really suggest just asking how to fix your Python command instead

Comment: Or use the Python `requests` library and make the API call in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match when the value of `success` is `true` in a flexible way:

```
"success"\s*:\s*"?true"?
```

This will match all of these:

```
{ "success" : true }
{ "success" : "true" }
{ "success":true}
```

To be *strict* and match the above, but not imbalanced quotes like `{ "success" : "true }`, use this:

```
"success"\s*:\s*("?)true\1
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Not sure how I didn't think of a pattern like that.

Answer (score 2):

Since the caller knows that the response is `{ "success" : true }`, I can't think of any reason to not use `jq` in this case. For instance, you can try something like this:

```sh
if echo '{ "success" : true }' | jq --exit-status '.success == true' >/dev/null; then
    echo "success" 
    # Do something success is true in the response.
else
    echo "not success" response.
    # Do something else success is not true or absent in the 
fi
```

If you want to make an API call and get the response, you can easily pass the JSON response directly from wget to `jq` instead of going the roundabout way of storing it in an intermediate variable by tweaking it like this:

```sh
if wget --timeout 10 -O - -q -t 1 https://your.api.com/endpoint | jq --exit-status '.success == true' >/dev/null; then
    echo "success"
else
    echo "not success"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend not doing it that way.

We used to do it this way long ago and got into trouble when the response code is "200 OK" but receiving `{"success": false}` seemed to contradict each other.

A better approach is to use the response status codes instead.

Simply return 200 OK if success is true otherwise return the appropriate error status code if its not.

https://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html

EDIT:
Bash script to help:

```
COOKIE_FILE="cookies.txt"
SERVER_IP="172.1.2.3"
LOGFILE="logs/api-calls.log"
WGETLOGFILE="logs/last-api-call.log"

#Helper function
on_wget_err ( )
  {
  EXITCODE=${1}
  case ${EXITCODE} in
    0) RESULT="OK";;
    *) cat ${WGETLOGFILE} >> ${LOGFILE};
       grep "HTTP/1.1" ${WGETLOGFILE} | gawk '{print substr($0,16)}'
       exit 0;;
  esac
  }


if wget -O - -qT 4 -t 1 ${SERVER_IP} > /dev/null; then
  echo "Server is up"
  wget -S -O - --load-cookies ${COOKIE_FILE} "http://${SERVER_IP}${SERVER_ADDRESS}/my/api?param=$1" 2> ${WGETLOGFILE}
  on_wget_err ${?}
  echo "API was successfull"
else
  echo "Server or network down"
  exit 1;
fi
```

Comment: Not sure why success would be false if the response was 200 but I guess rest errors happen. Probably better to validate based on the response code though. Thanks for providing the script, I will look into that approach.

Answer (score 0):

Your Python attempt was close. Here's a working one:

```
callResponse='{ "success" : true }'
status=$(echo "$callResponse" |
    python -c "import sys, json; print(json.load(sys.stdin)['success'])")
echo "$status"
```

Or alternatively, rewritten to go straight in an `if` statement:

```
callResponse='{ "success" : true }'
if echo "$callResponse" | python -c "import sys, json; sys.exit(0 if json.load(sys.stdin)['success'] else 1)"
then
  echo "Success"
fi
```

Comment: that works too, guess I just forgot to echo the response, thanks!